# @EndpointsAliasProperty and @Model.query_method causes BadRequestError(Key path element must not be incomplete:...)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore, endpoints-proto-datastore

Hey so right now I'm developing backend api using Google ProtoRPC and Endpoints. I'm using the `endpoints-proto-datastore` library.

So strange things happen here, here is the `EndpointsModel` class

```
class AssetData(EndpointsModel):
    type = msgprop.EnumProperty(AssetType, indexed=True)

    def auth_id_set(self, value):
        if ApplicationID.get_by_id(value) is None:
            raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException('no auth_id')

        self._auth_id = value

    @EndpointsAliasProperty(required=True, setter=auth_id_set, property_type=messages.IntegerField)
    def auth_id(self):
        return self._auth_id

    def app_id_set(self, value):
        if ApplicationID.query(ApplicationID.app_id == value).get() is None:
            raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException('wrong app_id')

        self._app_id = value

        if self.check_auth_app_id_pair(self.auth_id, value):
            self._app_id = value
        else:
            raise endpoints.BadRequestException('auth_id and app_id mismatch')

    @EndpointsAliasProperty(required=True, setter=app_id_set)
    def app_id(self):
        return self._app_id

    @staticmethod
    def check_auth_app_id_pair(authen_id, applic_id):
        dat = ApplicationID.get_by_id(authen_id)
        if dat.app_id != applic_id:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

and this is the API class

```
@endpoints.api(...)
class AssetDatabaseAPI(remote.Service):

    @AssetData.query_method(query_fields=('limit', 'order', 'pageToken', 'type', 'auth_id', 'app_id'),
                            path='assets', http_method='GET', name='assets.getAssetMultiple')
    def assets_get_multiple(self, query):
        return query
```

When I deploy this, everytime I tried to access `assets.getMultipleAssets` it just gives me this error
`raised BadRequestError(Key path element must not be incomplete: [ApplicationID: ])`. Strangely enough this only happen to method using `@Model.query_method`, I have other methods using the same system but using `@Model.method` and it just runs ok.

If I tried it in development server, sometimes it just gives me `RuntimeError: BadRequestError('missing key id/name',)` then if I just re-save the .py file and retry it, it will work (sometimes not and another re-save can also make the error happens again).

Can anyone tell me my mistake?
Thanks

Comment: I figured out the problem lies within ```if self.check_auth_app_id_pair(self.auth_id, value):
            self._app_id = value
        else:
            raise endpoints.BadRequestException('auth_id and app_id mismatch')``` in the `app_id_set`. The logic is a bit weird in there, I would like to put `check_app_id_auth_id()` before doing any API call but no idea how to do it, if the returned value is the `query`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is how you call this method - it's a static method, so you have to access it through class, not the instance (self):

```
    if AssetData.check_auth_app_id_pair(self.auth_id, value):
        self._app_id = value
    else:
        raise endpoints.BadRequestException('auth_id and app_id mismatch')
```

Comment: Apparently it still gives me the same error, I believe the error comes in `dat = ApplicationID.get_by_id(authen_id)` from `if self.check_auth_app_id_pair(self.auth_id, value):
            self._app_id = value`, and when the `authen_id` is None (since it is set late by the setter so it still stick with its default value `None`), it throws the error because to find a key you should not pass `None` as key. Anyway the logic itself is flawed, so I removed the requirement to put `app_id` so you don't need to check if the value is equal inside the setter